# Change text forecolor in a C# Winforms DataGridView Cell only for one character?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How can I change the text forecolor for each character that is a > in the following line, while keeping all other characters the default forecolor?

This is >> a test >>

I have tried the cellpainting event but have not had any luck.

Comment: I think this will point you in the right direction [How to: Customize Cells and Columns in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control by Extending Their Behavior and Appearance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/customize-cells-and-columns-in-the-datagrid-by-extending-behavior?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)